# Time Complexity of adding to a heap

Tags: data-structures

I have a Max Heapified Arraylist containing 'n' elements and want to add 'm' more elements to it. If tree height is k, the time complexity for the first 2^k elements would each be log n and for the next 2^k+1 would be log(n+1) each. How to generalize this and get an upper bound for adding these 'm' elements?

Comment: What's k? You started with m and n. Consider making your question more precise. Also, if it's homework, the SO rules require you to state that.

Comment: It's not a homework question just a design question me and my friend are working on.

Comment: Great. So what is k?

Comment: k I meant was the height of the binary tree and each level contains 2^k elements.

Comment: Usually, we don't bother too much and go with the simple `O(m log (m+n))` for the cost of adding `m` elements to a heap containing `n` elements. You could get a slightly tighter bound by going for a 'layer per layer' calculation, but honestly, the bound I wrote above does the job well.

Comment: @m.raynal Pretty sure that's tight for big-O.

Comment: @Gene yes, indeed, not only the 'stage per stage' calculation would be more complex, but on top of it it would all end up being `O(m log(m+n))` since it's asymptotic. Thanks for pointing that.